# Timer function in Flutter collapse in samsung s22 ultra . but works perfectly in other devices and even in s23 ultra . what would be the reason?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, samsung-mobile

in my quiz application i created a timer function which is given bellow ,

```
// function for handling Timer
  Future<void> examProgress() async {
    if (quizList.isNotEmpty) {
      if (_timer != null) {
        _timer?.cancel();
      }
      _timer = Timer.periodic(
        const Duration(milliseconds: 1),
        (Timer timer) async {
          if (progress.value >= 1 && !stop.value) {
            timer.cancel();
            isCorrectAnswer(false);
            isSkipped(false);
            if (!isTap.value) {
              (question?.isHintUsed ?? false) ? question?.point -= 5 : null;
              question?.errorCount++;
              question?.point -= 5;
              isSkipped(true);
              if (question?.errorCount == 3) {
                _isCompleted++;
                debugPrint("iscompleted ${_isCompleted.toString()}");
              }
            }
            await setDelay();
          } else if (stop.value) {
            timer.cancel();
            progress.value = 0;
          } else {
            progress.value = progress.value + (0.00015);
          }
        },
      );
    } else {
      Get.back();
      debugPrint("quiz_list_is_API_broke");
    }
  }
```

the questions changes with respect to the timer. it's not working in samsung s22 ultra. and works perfectly in all other devices and even in s23 ultra. can anyone suggest a possible chance for this issue ?

Comment: Is this the case to increase time interval  as s22 ultra have a high rate of response then your tasks goes under overflow??

Comment: thanks for respond, @G3nt_M3caj
yes. that's correct. time interval in s22 have higher than i setted in code. the task goes down with it and made a mess. 
it's working in other high performance devices like iPhone14 pro , and s23 ultra.
 do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Usually Duration(milliseconds: 1) is used for ONE SHOT task not for repeated operations. Depends on what is the need to have an interval so small. If it's to update the screen that is 4K is also tu small rate. So I suggest to increase the interval (take in mind 4K have a 60fps means 1000 millisecond /60 fps  = 16.66 millisecond every update of the screen ). Do your counts.

Comment: ok. then how does it works properly in s23 ultra which is enhanced w.r.t s22 ultra ? that made me confuse @G3nt_M3caj